# qsort: Sort 1 Dimension of 3D array in C

Tags: c, arrays, sorting

I have a 3D array: float `input[2][50][1000];`

I want to quick sort it from:

```
qsort (x, sizeof(x)/sizeof(*x), sizeof(*x), comp);
```

where comp is

```
int comp (const void * elem1, const void * elem2) {
    float f = *((float*)elem1);
    float s = *((float*)elem2);
    if (f > s) return  1;
    if (f < s) return -1;
    return 0;
}
```

I just want to sort 1 dimension of my 3D array, i.e I want to sort `input[0][temp][0]`, `input[0][temp][1]`, `input[0][temp][2]` and so on.

Ques: What do I replace `x` with? 
Forgive me if it sounds stupid

Comment: Ultimately this is to sort 1000 elements from `input[0][temp][0]..input[0][temp][999]`, is that correct ?

Comment: @WhozCraig That figure may not be equal to thousand but yah that dimension only. It may be less too like till 50. But how does that matter?

Comment: @WhozCraig Yah that should be float, could you please write an answer. And yah about the 1000 thing, i am declaring it till 1000 but maybe i fill elements upto 100 only and if so i will sort upto 100 only

Comment: Sure, `item[0][temp]`

Comment: Note: despite the name, `qsort()` may sort using a different algorithm than "quick sort".

Comment: possible duplicate of [qSort not Sorting my array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23027981/qsort-not-sorting-my-array)

Comment: @WhozCraig This is not a duplicate, man i asked that later. And they are different and you know that and this question's answer is just the comment that I have recently upvoted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
float (*x)[1000] = &input[0][temp];
qsort (x, sizeof(*x)/sizeof(**x), sizeof(**x), comp);
```